# How to remove warnings in visualization-app that depends on multiple versions of same dependency?

Tags: here-olp, harp.gl

While creating visualization-app as mentioned in https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/data-visualization-library/dev_guide/pages/install-generator.html, get a warning that `"requires a peer of three@^0.104.0 but none is installed."`.

However in the `package.json`, we already have dependency on `three` but at version `0.99.0`.
Also the source versions mentioned in the warning e.g. `@here/harp-lines@0.2.3`, are at lower version in `package.json` , i.e. `"@here/harp-lines": "^0.2.1"`
When I run the web server, I do get the basemap and userAuthorize form. However am unable to see anything in the perhaps "load file" (since the page fragment is blank) widget.

Steps provided at: https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/data-visualization-library/dev_guide/pages/install-generator.html
This generates the application, but with warnings.
Selected *"from geojson file"* (option 5) while creating project.
On running the application, and then filling in the authentication information, it does display a basemap. However nothing else could be done.

Here is the warning that is seen on the console:

```
npm WARN @here/harp-lines@0.2.3 requires a peer of three@^0.104.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @here/harp-datasource-protocol@0.3.3 requires a peer of three@^0.104.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @here/harp-mapview@0.8.3 requires a peer of three@^0.104.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @here/harp-map-controls@0.2.3 requires a peer of three@^0.104.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @here/harp-materials@0.2.3 requires a peer of three@^0.104.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @here/harp-text-canvas@0.2.3 requires a peer of three@^0.104.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @here/harp-geometry@0.1.2 requires a peer of three@^0.104.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with harp.gl library that we use. They published API breaking changes without increasing minor  version. It will be fixed with the release of OLP 2.5.

If you dont want to wait for 2.5 release please do the following:

- run generator so application will be generated
- remove node_modules folder under the path of generated application to cleanup the list of installed dependencies
- open package.json file in any text editor or IDE
- remove "^" symbol before version number for all dependencies that are started from prefix "@here/harp-" and for those specific modules: datastore-api, hype and oauth-requester. By doing that we are pointing NPM to use the exact version as it is specified in package.json
- add new dependency     "@here/harp-text-canvas": "0.2.1", to the package.json
- then run "npm install" to install dependencies according to the changes you made to package.json
- then run "npm start"